# Is Azure AD B2C able to dynamic grouping?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

Checking the AAD from a B2C tenant, and the option for membership type is greyed out. I tried to check MS.docs but didn't find some information about it... Maybe it's not possible? Maybe missing license?

Note: It's an AAD from B2C tenant, I'm global admin for this AAD with AD P2 enabled.

AAD B2C Tenant new group image ref:
[image: AAD B2C Tenant new group image ref]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dynamic Groups are not supported in B2C tenants.  These are features of a standard AAD tenant, you can't assign licenses to a B2C tenant.

Comment: Thank you ! I was suspecting that was not possible!